# Text not showing up once added to HTML tags using Javascript but DOM Inspector says otherwise

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

```
        var input_choices = document.createElement("div");
    input_choices.setAttribute('id', "input_choices");





    for(var i=0;i<survey["questions"][1]["choices"].length;i++){

        var inputs = document.createElement("input");
        inputs.setAttribute('id',"inputvalue");
        inputs.setAttribute('type',"radio");
        inputs.setAttribute('name',"choice");

        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = survey["questions"][1]["choices"][i];


        input_choices.appendChild(inputs);
        inputs.appendChild(label);
        console.log(label);
        }


    form.appendChild(form_title);
    form.appendChild(input_choices);        
    q_card.appendChild(form);
    main_content.append(q_card);
```

The image and code above shows the problem im facing. I added text value to the label and added the label to the inputs tag but its not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending label as a child of input, they should be siblings as inputs cannot have children. You should wrap them both in a span or some sort of enclosing element and then append that to input_choices.

Should be able to do something like this:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
wrapper.appendChild(label);
wrapper.appendChild(inputs);
input_choices.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input elements can't have children.

Either:

- The `input` should be a descendant of the `label`  *or*
- The `input` should have no descendants, the `label` should be elsewhere (e.g. as a sibling of the `input`) and the `for` attribute of the `label` should match the `id` of the `input`

NB: You have `inputs.setAttribute('id',"inputvalue");` in a loop but an `id` must be **unique** in a document

```
label.appendChild(inputs);
input_choices.appendChild(label);
```